# WSL 2 (Debian) main user is not a sudoer: how to reset it?

Tags: sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason my main and only user in Debian (Windows Subsystem For Linux v2) **is not a sudoer any more**.

```
sudo apt-get install <whatever>
myuser is not in the sudoers file
```

I know I can add myself to sudoers via `usermod -aG sudo myuser` but how do that since I'm the only user?
Also, If I try to run `su` to workaround this, my wsl password is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can switch to `root` from a normal command prompt (cmd.exe)

> debian config --default-user root

and then re-add the user to sudoers in a new wsl instance

> usermod -aG sudo myuser

finally, switch to my user

> su - myuser

Answer (score 2):

In command prompt, start distro as root:

```
wsl -d MY_DISTRO --user root
```

Then run:

```
usermod -aG sudo MY_USER
```